# Condition in a SQL statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I get this error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
> LINE 14: FROM dat.unit du

This is the query:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT  extract (epoch 
     FROM
         (SELECT avg_freq  
          FROM tlm.data_qa_tele_freq(du.id, null, now()::timestamp - interval '0.5 day', now()::timestamp)) 
    )) AS "ASDF"
FROM 
    dat.unit du
```

Returns this column:

[image]

As you can see it returns null if there is not data and an real number. What I must get is the values which are bigger than 30.

Comment: What's the DBMS you're currently using?

Comment: DBMS postgresql

Comment: please show 1st column as well..

Comment: @JAOdev its because its a case whenever the case doesnot match it shows NULL.simple

Comment: I reckon these are all stored as as string beacuse 50.50.50 >30 returns true in postgres..
you need a convertion to number but before that values should all be number not as two decimals in there...rest you knwo what you require!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `CASE` statement, you should use a `WHERE` clause here.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
    (SELECT EXTRACT(epoch FROM
        (SELECT avg_freq  
         FROM tlm.data_qa_tele_freq(du.id, 
                                    null, 
                                    now()::timestamp - interval '0.5 day',
                                    now()::timestamp) 
      ) 
    )) AS "ASDF",
  FROM dat.unit du
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE "ASDF" > 30
```

If the "ASDF" field is a string instead of a integer-like value, you need to use the typecasting operation:

```
WHERE "ASDF"::INTEGER > 30
```

Also I'd recommend to check the `CASE` full syntax on the [official documentation](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-case/).

Comment: Thanks but I get: ERROR:  column "ASDF" does not exist when I use where and without where it runs and shows "ASDF" column.

Comment: You're right, you need a subquery to use the alias. Check the updated answer.